# Idiom for an explanatory note at the bottom of a float, other than the caption?

Tags: floats, captions

I've placed a float in my document, and given it a caption, saying what the float contains (e.g. "Effect of Foo on Bar, by year"). But - I also want to add a bit of text below the main content of the float, to make some finer point regarding that content, which is not discussed in the body of the text.

Naturally, I won't add this to the caption, which describes the float generally and fits well in a list-of-figures/list-of-tables/etc. I could just write this note between the float environment's begin and end commands, but that will make my float take up more width than it should, and I'll also need to manually play with the font size and maybe other aspects of it.

Is there some common "idiom" for adding some explanatory notes to floats? Or at least one kind of floats (figures, tables etc.)?

Note: I'm talking about text which should be typeset in the final version of the document, not a means of communicating information to collaborators on the document.

Comment: Do you refer to footnotes, marginpar, or a reference into the appendix?

Comment: Are you referring to a *legend*?

Comment: You don't need `\caption` to add text to a figure or table.  What `\caption` mostly does is increment the figure or table counter and send a copy to the aux file to be used in the LOF,   Otherwise the figure or table is formatted like the rest of the document (except it sets `\parindent` and `\parskip` to 0pt).

Comment: @Mico: That's a good guess to make, but - no, I don't.

Comment: @MS-SPO: Not a reference into the appendix; I have nowhere to 'hang' a footnote on; and marginpar... hmm... can one make that look elegant in any way?

Comment: How do you want to present the extra information? Like an info box, for example? Why isn‘t it part of the body by concept?

Comment: You can also use the optional argument of `\caption`, with the format `\caption[short description that will be shown in the list-of-X]{long caption that is shown in the body}`.

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34190/creating-a-second-caption-for-a-figure-that-wont-appear-in-the-figures-list-in which seems very close to your use case.

Comment: Or `copyrightbox` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236605/how-to-add-correct-citing-of-figures) which can also be below the image and used for things other than copyright notices.